# Setting Bitrate for Serial-Over-USB Device to 256000

Tags: usb, macos

I need to communicate with a serial-over-USB device which requires a bitrate of 256000 but macOS 11.6.7 (x86) and 12.4 (M1) are refusing to do that.

```
# stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-141130 256000
stty: tcsetattr: Invalid argument
```

The device in question is using a Prolific PL2303 chipset. Is there a way to get macOS to use the bitrate I need, maybe with custom drivers?

Comment: Can you try `stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-141130 ispeed 256000` and `stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-141130 ospeed 256000`? The device may not support the baud rate specified, you may want to try another rate (for a list of baud rates, see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/what-standard-uart-rates-are-there/566949#566949).

Comment: Both commands give the same error, and as stated in the question the device requires 256000.

Comment: Your question is formulated in a way that is a bit confusing. Are you actually trying to communicate with the serial-over-USB device itself? (i.e. communicate with for example a USB to RS-232 dongle). Usually you have a UBS to RS-232 dongle connected to your Mac where you attach the actual device you want to communicate with. Is this the case? - If so, what is the device you want to communicate with? - Usually such devices have the option of using several different baud rates.

Comment: The device in question is a m2m Blue-450, a USB device with an internal Bluetooth stack. Its firmware requires a bitrate of 256000 bps for communication, and it works perfectly fine with that bitrate under Windows and no, it does not have any options to change that bitrate.

Comment: @Bombe I have updated my answer with the details for your device. It seems there are multiple options for getting it working on macOS. The unfortunate choice of the non-conventional 256000 baud rate means that it doesn't play well with the built-in driver, but there are multiple other drivers available for the USB-to-serial bridge.

Answer (score 3):

The common drivers for the PL2303 chipset all have a maximum baud rate setting of 230400.

The PL2303 chipset in *some* variants itself does support higher baudrates, but the rest of the hardware (i.e. your "serial over USB device") and the cabling needs to support it as well. 256000 is not a common baud rate, so you usually won't see much support for it.

You did not include any details about the device you're trying to communicate with. Most often those devices come with baud rate settings that allow you to use other baud rates - I suggest that you find out if that is possible for your device, and then set a lower baud rate.

If that doesn't work, you can make your own driver for the PL2303 chipset - or try to modify one of the open source drivers.

An easier way forward would probably be to run a Linux virtual machine on your Mac and setup the communication in there.

Note however that on Linux again only certains variants of the PL2303 chip supports setting a 2560000 baud rate. For example the PL2303HXN chip supports a 256000 baud rate, but the PL2303HX does not. There are more than 10 variants.

Those variants that do not support the 256000 baud rate can instead be set to 230400 baud. That is the common baud rate nearest 256000 baud.

**UPDATE**

In the comments, you have now detailed that the device is an m2m Blue-450. This device contains a (now End-of-Lifed) BLE121LR Bluetooth LE module, which has an UART interface - and a Prolific PL2303HXD (also End-of-Lifed) for bridging that to USB.

The documentation for the BLE121LR lists 230400 as a common baud rate to use with it - they do not mention 256000 at all. The module allows for changing the baud rate through its configuration.

Unfortunately the documentation for the m2m Blue-450 is a bit unclear on configuration options. They list that 256000 baud is (very unfortunate) standard setting, they have chosen. The wording seems to imply that this is just a standard, and thus that you might be able to change it. I have only found the documentation in German though, and my German is a bit rusty.

Another thing they detail in the documentation is that only Windows 7 and Linux is supported. I assume this means that they are aware that other systems are not supported. You might want to contact their support to enquire whether they have a solution now for the Mac.

Prolific hosts a macOS driver for the chip on their web site here:

https://www.prolific.com.tw/UserFiles/files/PL2303HXD_G_Mac%20Driver_v2_1_0_20210311.zip

You might want to try it to see if they have made it possible to use 256000 baud.

I have checked the [open-source driver](https://github.com/bjarnoldus/mac-osx-pl2303) as well as the commercial mac-usb-serial.com driver for the PL2303 - they do not support 256000 baud.

For the open-source driver I have found that they write in the documentation that it does only supports up to 230400 baud, but in the source code, it does seem that 256000 would be supported - if the chipset in the device supports it. So you might want to have a go with the open-source driver to see if that works.

I would suggest these five options for trying to get the device to work on your Mac in order of priority:

1. Try the driver from Prolific.
2. Try the open-source driver for old macOS versions, if you're running one of those.
3. You have the device working on Windows. Use that and see if you have direct access to the BLE121LR module over the connection. If that is the case, you could be able to use the configuration commands listed in [this document](https://silabs-prod.adobecqms.net/documents/public/user-guides/UG210-Bluetooth-LE-Module-Configuration-Guide.pdf) to set a different baud rate (for use with macOS).
4. Boot Linux in a virtual machine on your Mac and access the device from there.
5. Create your own driver based on the [open-source driver](https://github.com/bjarnoldus/mac-osx-pl2303). This is easiest if you're not running a recent macOS version - which I assume you're not, as you're using relatively old hardware and recent Macs have Bluetooth LE built-in. The change is relatively simple (if you happen to be a programmer ofcourse), as we have the Linux driver source code to compare with - and the baud rate configuration logic is not complex.

Comment: So, the driver in use (probably some driver by Apple as I haven’t installed any other drivers) is the one that denies `stty`’s request for the bitrate?

Comment: And from what I can gather from the – rather sparse – documentation the chip is a PL2303HXD.

Comment: @Bombe Yes, it is the driver that denies `stty`'s request for the bitrate.